# How do I create CSS scroll effects?

Tags: css

When the user scrolls the website downward and reaches a certain point, I want it to trigger a certain behavior. Example could be a change in text position.

Comment: javascript is to be used here :)

Comment: scroll effects shoud be done using javascript and not css

Comment: I suggest you delete "CSS" in your title and add javascript "tag" to your question

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of what you are describing using javascript:

```js
function winScroll() {
    if (window.pageYOffset > 1000) {
        window.alert('You have scrolled down the page more than 1000 pixels');
    }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll',winScroll,false);
```

```css
body {
height: 4000px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Keep scrolling down...</h1>
```

Comment: Can I create arbitrary points instead of using fixed positions? Instead of at 1000pixels, when the user reaches the bottom of an image, it triggers something?

Comment: Yes, that's straightforward enough. For any `targetImage`, you can find out how far the top of the image (including padding and borders) is offset from the top of the viewport (`var viewportOffset = targetImage.getBoundingClientRect(); var offsetTop = viewportOffset.top;`) and then then add `offsetTop` to `targetImage.offsetHeight` - that will you give the number of the pixels from the top of the viewport to the bottom of the image (including padding and borders).